# Python: How to test if a string contains one of strings in a list accent insensitive?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I need to test if a string contains one of strings in a list, ignoring the accents.

I tried using for + in + if + unidecode but without success:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

def temServentiaExclusiva(nome_orgao):
     #fix-me: pegar ids dinamicamente
    regras = [
        {'especializada_id':70, 'termos': [u'orfaos e sucessoes', u'familia']}
    ]

    for r in regras:
      #if(unidecode(nome_orgao) in s for s in r['termos']):
      if([t for t in r['termos'] if(t in unidecode(nome_orgao))]):
        return r['especializada_id']


print(temServentiaExclusiva('orfãos'))
print(temServentiaExclusiva('Cartório da 6ª Vara de Orfãos e Sucessões'))
```

The result was ***None*** :(

So, How can I achieve that?

Comment: You may want to add code to the start of `temServentiaExclusiva()` that will look through `nome_orgao` and find any characters with accents, and then change those characters to the versions without accents before checking.

Comment: @SpencerLutz this a "Proof of concepts" from something bigger

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a nested for loop, rather than a list comprehension:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

def temServentiaExclusiva(nome_orgao):
    regras = [
        {'especializada_id':70, 'termos': [u'orfaos e sucessoes', u'familia']}
    ]

    uni_nome_orgao = unidecode(nome_orgao).lower()

    for r in regras:
      for t in r['termos']:
          if uni_nome_orgao in t or t in uni_nome_orgao:
              return r['especializada_id']

print(temServentiaExclusiva('orfãos'))
```

The key is getting nome_orgao into a standard format, then checking it against all the termos. As you've already done, `unidecode` will remove all the accents. Add `.lower()` to the end to make everything lowercase. Then, iterate through each r in regras and each t in termos, and check if t is in uni_nome_orgao or uni_nome_orgao is in t.

Hope that helps!

Comment: do you know why the second one does not work? https://repl.it/repls/PurpleSizzlingAddition

Comment: Do you want to know if nome_orgao is in any of the termos, or if any of the termos is in nome_orgao?

Comment: could it be both?

Comment: Note on the accent-stripping part: depending on the task-specific definition of "accent insensitive", `unidecode` might not be the right tool, in particular if you want to strip accents from scripts other than Latin, or if it's a problem that `unidecode` turns "€" into "EUR" and "1°" into "1deg". Because `unidecode` is strict ASCII-fication. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string/)'s a range of alternative approaches.